# Can't use flashplayer since upgrading to 19.04?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I get this message:

[image]

And it never actually runs on right click + clicking the menu item.

Comment: Are you able to enable Flash for  [this page](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) to confirm that it's installed? I succeeded in doing so on 19.04 with both Google Chrome and Chromium.

Comment: @Flash is "enabled", but still showing the above image, and when you co tell it to run, nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm.. It may be [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1826739). I too have problems on 19.04 with Chromium and Google Chrome. Flash works fine with Firefox, though.

Comment: This is a [Chromium bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1825497), and it's about to be fixed very soon. (Already fixed in eoan.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem to what I had. I switched to a browser with no built in flash in it (i.e Firefox, Opera , Vivaldi) and used [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html.en) to install a fresh version of flash (use *flashplugin* to install it) It appears chrome's built-in one is broken in 19.04. You can also try disabling it and use the method above to reinstall it, although I am not sure if that will work.

Edit: Response to below comment: Unsure. I switched to Firefox. Quantum is relatively fast.

Comment: Does it work for you with Opera and/or Vivaldi? They (unlike Firefox) use precisely the same plugin as Chrome/Chromium, which would indicate that it's a Chrome/Chromium problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with the sandbox as --no-sandbox "fixed it" dont use this as a permanent solution though as it is unsafe